# 'refer friends to enroll' is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I was writing a paragraph for a friend and after finishing, I realized that it doesn't sound quite right. I feel as though there are issues with the grammar.

For example :
'refer friends to enroll'

- the 'friends to enroll' sounds particularly off even though logically it's fine as it's an infinitive verb following a noun.

> *If you are able to successfully refer friends to enroll in all our Loving Tree English Language courses, both parties will receive a $400 tuition fee waiver.
> Not to mention, if enrollment in tutorial or preschool classes are successful , the second month tuition fee is half-price.*

Comment: The only (and there were only two) Google hits I've found for "refer them to enrol" were both from distant countries. Certainly, 'refer + DO + to-infinitive' sounds ungrammatical to me. But 'advise/persuade/ask/beg/tell/forbid... (quite a few but not all sensible-looking verbs) + DO + to-infinitive' are all totally grammatical: 'We got them to enrol in the new course'. // I can see why 'refer' is pragmatically desired here; a pity it doesn't behave. 'Persuade' doesn't sound too selfless and 'advise' isn't directly result-geared.

Comment: You could always leave off 'to enroll'. It's hopefully obvious that a referral is for enrollment.

Comment: '...refer friends to enroll...'  should be "If you refer friends to our Loving Tree English Language courses and they enrol..."

Comment: Doesn't this solve the issue: "To successfully refer friends **who** enroll"?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask people to ‘refer friends to Loving Tree’

Or you could ‘invite them’ to enroll, but you can’t mix the two.

When you ‘refer somebody to something’ it is like referencing something in a library.

- I refer you to section 3, birds and animals
- I am referring to what you said yesterday

You refer someone *to* something (or someone)

You connect your friends to useful information. But, it is up to them to choose it, or not.

You can’t force people to reference their friends to you, like tickets in a library. You can only ask them to *invite* their friends to do so.

Also, you might clarify, the second month tuition fee is half-price *for whom?*

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/refer-to

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not correct.**

"Refer to" something means to direct someone to something, but then the 'something' should be a noun.

> I referred the student to the department of education.

"Verb **to** verb" means you should do verb 1 in order to accomplish the second. Again not what you want to say.

The correct structure is tricky. I would suggest:

> If you refer students to the school, and they enroll in a class, then both parties...

Answer (score -1):

You could either remove ***' to enroll'***
or add ***' your friends'***

Basically, the first option works better in my opinion......

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please *explain* which you think is better and why. Citations from authoritative sources lend authenticity to your answer.